# Live tile in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to learn livetile in windows phone 7,

http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPushNotificationsLab/Exercise-2-Introduction-to-the-Toast-and-Tile-Notifications-for-Alerts

I referred this above example, i dono much about wcf.

i am getting this error,
could not start service host. HTTP could not register URL
http://+8000/RegirstatorService/.
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace
namespace(see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).

can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Your question is far too vague to allow anyone to answer it. Exactly what are you doing and where does it fail?

Comment: i just downloaded the example and run it.. it shows this notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats a fairly standard thing you need to do to get wcf running. Log in as admin then run netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user (as the msdn doc says).

That then give you permission to use the namespace in future and it should all work fine

Edit: also giving you an up vote to counteract the down. There was plenty of info to ansewr the question

Comment: do i have to create any wcf service for this?